# Element inserted in contenteditable not firing ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I need to provide user functionality which will allow him to add some placeholders to textarea, something like email templates. I've managed to find caret position and insert there newly created node, but even though I'm using `$compile` ng-click is not firing `doStuff()` function.

```
angular
    .module('app.shared')
    .directive('placeholderInput', placeholderInput);

function placeholderInput($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            content: '=',
            inputClass: '=',
            variables: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/js/shared/directives/placeholderInput.html',
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            scope.popoverOpen = false;
            var textArea = elem[0].querySelector('.placeholder-input-textarea');
            scope.insertPlaceholder = function(variable) {
                textArea.focus();
                var range = getRange(textArea);
                var newNode = document.createElement('span');
                newNode.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
                newNode.setAttribute('class', 'label label-primary');               
                newNode.setAttribute('ng-click', 'doStuff()');
                newNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(variable.label));
                $compile(newNode)(scope);
                range.insertNode(newNode);
                // var span = angular.element($compile('<span class="label label-primary" contenteditable="false" ng-click="doStuff()">span</span>')(scope));
                scope.content = angular.element(textArea).html();
                scope.popoverOpen = false;
            }
            scope.doStuff = function() {
                console.info(123);
            }
            var getRange = function(element) {
                var range;
                var caretOffset = 0;
                var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
                var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
                var sel;
                if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
                    sel = win.getSelection();
                    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
                        range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                    }
                } else if ( (sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
                    range = doc.body.createTextRange();
                }
                return range;
            };
        }
    };
}
```

view:

```
<div>
    <div ng-model="content" class="placeholder-input-textarea {{inputClass}}" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <button uib-popover-template="'placeholderInputVariables.html'" popover-placement="right" popover-is-open="popoverOpen" type="button">+</button>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="placeholderInputVariables.html">
    <div class="list-group">
        <button ng-repeat="variable in variables" type="button" ng-click="insertPlaceholder(variable)" class="list-group-item">{{variable.label}}</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Please help. Maybe you'll get some other ideas how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just change the order of these two lines:

from

```
 $compile(newNode)(scope);
 range.insertNode(newNode);
```

to

```
 range.insertNode(newNode);
 $compile(newNode)(scope);
```